# How to modify entered value in string filter

Tags: javascript, string, extjs, filter, extjs3

I have a string filter for 3 columns in my grid. This is working fine. In third column whose dataindex is `abc` I want to modify entered value.

For example if I press 0 then it filtered all the data which having 0. I want to press **'No'** instead of 0 to filter. Similarly I want to use **'Yes'** instead of 1 to filter data with 1.

My Code for creating filter.

```
this.filters = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({
    filters: this.filter,
    local: true,
    autoReload: false,
});
this.features = [this.filters];
this.plugins = [this.filters];
```

Code for inserting filter.

```
gridEl.filter.push({
    type: header.getAttribute("FILTER"),
    dataIndex: header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX"),
    encode: false,
    metaID: header.getAttribute("M"),
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should show us your code

Comment: You can show us the code and what you tried to do?

Comment: @YosvelQuintero IS now fine for you ?

Comment: JSFiddle/Sencha fiddle would have been easy to understand better.

Comment: @VinodGubbala please refer this filter. In this I want to use specific input which is defined by me. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per you example http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html
Create your own BooleanFilter and add you condition. See my snippet below.

```js
Ext.define('MyFilter.CustomBooleanFilter', {
   extend: 'Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter',
   alias: 'gridfilter.customboolean',

   validateRecord : function (record) {
       var rValue = record.get(this.dataIndex),
           fValue = this.getValue();
       return rValue == fValue || rValue == (fValue == "1" || "true".indexOf(fValue.toLowerCase()) == 0 || "yes".indexOf(fValue.toLowerCase()) == 0);
    }
});
```

See the working demo here. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f5l

Let me know if you are not looking for this. I did as per what my understanding is
EDIT: But I feel if this is what you want, then use Boolean Filter to change the text you want. Like Yes and No. Its more convenient for user than enter it. As you have only two values.

Comment: I am working on this. I assume your edit is over. I will notify you once I am done.

Comment: Added my last comment. Sorry for so many edits. I am just excited to play with this.... :D . Never saw those before....

Comment: I am using string filter because rest other column is string. only this column is vollean. I am changing filter type for this is as Boolean. Also I am using ext 3.4 so can not create alias

Comment: Ohh... Yours is 3.4.... The example given was 4.2. So I worked on that framework. Can you try to find an online example for 3.4?

Comment: Ya, I am trying in my code itself. Very close to solution. Hope it will work

Comment: Hope it works. You can always share a small example in fiddle and I can help you in solving it.

Comment: Your return statement is based on yes and no or true and false

Comment: As I don't know what exactly you want. You can convert that condition based on your requirement

Comment: One last question. filter type of the column will be string or Boolean. Because when I am setting Boolean I am getting checkbox of "Yes" and "No".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120766/discussion-between-user6474292-and-vinod-gubbala).